# Calls to an API fails after some time when multiple users are logged in and using the application. Is there a way to solve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, timeout

I am making some calls to an api that syncs and saves appointments to/from my application and mail agenda which is most commonly Outlook mails. The calls to the api are made from a web application and it is working fine for some time but then immediately after a few hours, the calls are failed. This continues for some time and starts to work again after some time.

The DefaultConnectionLimit was set to 100 in the beginning and during this scenario, the process stopped working after some time (Say 30 mins to 1 hour). Then DefaultConnectionLimit was set to 20 and in this case, it worked fine for 3-4 hours and stopped working after that. I don't know  if this is the actual cause but just mentioning.

The code where the call to the api is made from the web application is mentioned below :

```
public bool SyncNewAppToExch(string encryptedAppSyncDetails)
  {
      try
      {
          string result = string.Empty;
          JArray paramList = new JArray();
          paramList.Add(encryptedAppSyncDetails);
          var emailApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailApiUrl"].ToString();
          Uri baseAddress = new Uri(emailApiUrl);
          var url = "/api/EmailProcess/ManualSaveAppointments";
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
          Task.Run(() => client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, paramList)).Wait(5000);
          var responseMessage = true;
          if (responseMessage)
              return true;
          else
              return false;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

The exception that follows the api call failure reads :

Exception : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.get_Result()

Comment: I think you must check server Configuration on which your api's are deployed, why it goes down after some limit

Comment: Your code has few code smells that can cause issues, 1 you should use using statement on client variable; 2 your `Task.Run.Wait()` construct is pointless and a bit harmful either make your method async or if you need synchronous call use webclient or Webrequest  and serialize your content manually; To track down the cause of your error its nice to have exceptions logged somewhere. If you knew what exception is thrown your question would not be so hard to answer.

Comment: @Rafal I have managed exceptions and the exception logged reads "One or more errors occurred. at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()"

Comment: @AnusreeS read more, its generic AggregateExcetion find inner most `InnerException` and post it. -> exception.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException until its null and move back one level. or post full text of your log. Hope you are logging exception not exceotion.Message.

Comment: @Rafal The full exception is as follows: Exception : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task1.get_Result(

Comment: So your task got cancelled this can happen with Wait (int) when your task is processing longer than given int so 5s given this I would load test your ManualSaveAppointments it looks like it takes longer and longer to end or its waiting for something like previous request to end eventually waiting longer than 5s

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a new HttpClient object each time you want to make a call, you are not using it appropriately.  HttpClient may continue to use sockets even if it is no longer being used and this will likely cause socket exhaustion under load.  [You can see more on this topic here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/)

You should create a single instance and reuse it.  If you are using .Net core it would be a better idea to use the HttpClientFactory.

In addition, using Task.Run to call an async method is not wise.  <strike>You are setting yourself up for a deadlock.</strike>  It would be much better to mark your method as async and await, if possible.  Since you are effectively doing fire and forget, the way you have done this if your App Domain shuts down this work will be lost.

If you need to do this, you should at least consider registering your task as such:

HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => SendMailAsync(user.Email));

The short answer is that it is difficult to say what your issue is, it could be one of several problems.

Comment: Task.Run.Wait will not produce deadlock as its spawning thread and waiting for it. Its just useless code.

Comment: I know this is old, but thank you so much for this! I had multiple calls to an API using the same HttpClient and it kept failing after 2 calls, but now with only 1 reused HttpClient it works perfectly!